# Exception when using variable as part of tag in Django template (Wagtail CMS)

Tags: django, django-templates, wagtail

Setting up a Django/Wagtail CMS site. Trying to make a template for images, which takes sizing as an variable, and including the template with:

```
{% include "patterns/molecules/media/image.html" with media=page.featured_image caption=page.image_caption imgclass="extra-wide" sizing="fill-854x480" %}
```

And then in the template, I am using the following code:

```
    {% with sizing as size %}
        {% if size %}
            {% image media size as img %}
        {% else %}
            {% image media fill-1280x720 as img %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
```

However, it ends up with an exception:

```
InvalidFilterSpecError at /slug/
Unrecognised operation: size
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/slug/
Django Version: 2.1.7
Exception Type: InvalidFilterSpecError
```

Comment: If your sizing is a string you're passing into the template `include`, why not just write it in the `image.html` include? And the `{% with sizing as size %}` could be removed in favour of simply using `sizing` instead of `size` (it's creating an extra var in the template, which will cause more logic and confusion in the template in the long run.

Comment: So I'm looking into this and it seems that `{% include .... with sizing="string-here" %}` is then using the string version of the sizing in the `{% image %}` tag which isn't working as you'd expect. It might be better to do the image sizing logic inside the included file. `{% if size == "fill-1280x720" %}{% image media fill-1280x720 as img %}{% endif %}`. I'm not 100% certain this is _the_ solution to go with, but it's certainly _an_ option to go with.